# import {take} from 'rxjs/operators/take' but 'rxjs/operators/take' folder doesn't exist

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm developing an Angular 2 application using the Angular template of Visual Studio. For the web service I'm using ASP.NET Core 2. This is the `package.json` file contents:

```
{
  "name": "AngularWebApplication",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.9.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "mdn-polyfills": "^5.2.0",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I have added `@angular/material` and then I need to update all @angular packages to version 5.1.0 and some of them to version 5.0.1. I have also update rxjs to version 5.5.5.

When I start the app I get the error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/take"

But I have found the following files in folder `\node_modules\rxjs\operators\`:

- take.d.ts
- take.js
- take.js.map
- takeLast.d.ts
- takeLast.js
- takeLast.js.map
- takeUntil.d.ts
- takeUntil.js
- takeUntil.js.map
- takeWhile.d.ts
- takeWhile.js
- takeWhile.js.map

The problem is that there are several files in `node_modules` that **I HAVEN'T MODIFIED** with the following import:

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take'
```

I don't think I have to modify those files in `node_modules` folder to remove the take from the path (`from 'rxjs/operators'`).

I have also run `npm install -g @angular/cli` without successful.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should be using it as `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: @VansFannel can you post where you put the fix (the exact file)?  I feel I have littered every single ts file with the accepted answer with no luck.  Aslo, my rsjx doesn't have an 'Operators' folder, only 'Operator'?????  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mike_G I don't know. I think the error is due to update Angular 4.2.5 to Angular 5.1.0. I have created an empty project and update it to Angular 6.0.0-beta4 without any problem but If I do the same with my previous project I get the same error. I have deleted also node_modules folder without success.

Comment: @Aravind I'm not going to change the import in nodules that I HAVEN'T MODIFIED. This is not the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was due to mismatch in angular versions. 
run

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and build, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'` inside the service/component

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: As @VansFannel commented, the rxjs doesn't have an operators folder and I see only Operator folder. Can you please help?

Comment: I have to downgrade the version of rxjs from 5.4 to 5.3 and then it allowed 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: I don't think this solved my problem. Where is the service/component? rxjs doesn't have a folder called operators, I don't think adding an import to a folder that doesn't exist will solve this problem.

Comment: you need to install rxjs

Comment: @Sajeetharan rxjs is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Per [@Kirk-Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin)'s [answer on another SO post,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847555/3443552):

> Once you've installed the updated version, you'll need to get webpack to rebuild in the correct order. You might be able to get that to happen with a solution-level rebuild of the project(s), but if not, you can run the following to force webpack to build correctly:
>
> `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`
>
> `webpack`

This, coupled with upgrading `rxjs` to `v5.5.0`, resolved the issue for me.