# Adding Angular Material to Asp.Net Core 2 SPA

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material, asp.net-core-2.0

I cant seem to get this to work.  The bits and pieces I find on SO and the net are out of date and seem incomplete.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyProj.Site",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.3",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "5.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.6.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.vendor.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
    '@angular/cdk'
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'hammerjs/hammer',
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css',


];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

and my app.shared.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        MatButtonModule
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

My vendor.config compiles fine.  When I debug the project in VS2017, I get this error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/take" at webpackMissingModule
>   (C:\Users\Mike\Source\MyProj\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15733:140)

Any help on where I should reference the rxjs modules would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@angular/material` to the `treeShakableModules` const in the *webpack.config.vendor.js*? I am guessing on this. :)

Comment: I have, and that causes the webpack.config.vendor.js to not compile.  The error is almost the same:  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ` 'rxjs/operators/map in ..\node_modules\@angular\cdk\esm5'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen in the [package.json](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.0.1/package.json), `@angular/material` has the following dependency:

```
"rxjs": "^5.5.5"
```

You have `"rxjs": "5.4.2"` in your `package.json`, which is obviously a little behind this. I actually found a Github [issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/483) for the flex-layout angular package, which suggested uprading `rxjs` to `5.5` solves the same issue in that package. I just tried this with your setup and can confirm that it works using 5.5.5 as above.

EDIT: Once you've installed the updated version, you'll need to get webpack to rebuild in the correct order. You might be able to get that to happen with a solution-level rebuild of the project(s), but if not, you can run the following to force webpack to build correctly:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack
```

You might not have `webpack` installed globally - if not, you can use the following (assuming Windows):

```
.\node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
.\node_modules\.bin\webpack
```

Comment: that leads to a new error:  NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.  Are you using the same version of material and angular as in my package.json?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a link to a working sln?  Ive been fiddling with this for more than a day now with no luck.

Comment: Actually, I managed to reproduce the same error. I added an edit to explain how I resolved that. If that doesn't work, I'll provide the Github repo.

Comment: yeah, I'm going to need a git.  My webpack.config.vendor.js compiles fine, but when I run webpack, It errors out with the same error mentioned in OP.

Comment: lol..Im dying over here.  Yours works without issue, I copy and paste the 3 files mentioned above, and mine fails.  Oh well, I appreciate the help.  I can go over my files, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Adding latest version of Angular Material in **ASP.net Core 2.0** with default installed node packages is more difficult and time consuming for resolving package dependencies.

Use below version of angular material in package.json

> **`"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12"`**
>
> **`"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12"`**

followed by run below command to install it.

> `npm install --save`